# Sudden loss of access to `/_vti_bin/ListData.svc`

Tags: 2010, rest, listdata.svc

Between yesterday and today, all my requests to the "`ListData.svc`" API thingy have gone broken. Every request results as an Error 500, and asks me to check the server logs (to which I do not have access).

Can I get any clue about what could possibly have happened that would lead to those consequences?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it.
Turns out someone changed the name of a list, and gave it a name that was already used by another list. This doesn't break anything, it seems, but it does break the REST API, even beyond the name conflicts.